# Powershell SCCM - query distribution point config to get if pxe enable unknown computer support etc

Tags: powershell, sccm

I've made the following script :

```
cls

$siteCode = 'AB1'
$serverName = 'S203S1'

# Query SCCM to find the specific Distribution Point
$dp = Get-CMDistributionPoint -SiteSystemServerName $serverName
$dpProperties = $DP.EmbeddedProperties
if ($dpProperties) {
    $dpName = $dpProperties.Name
    $enablePxeSupport = $dpProperties.EnablePxeSupportForClients
    $allowPxeRequests = $dpProperties.RespondToPxeRequests
    $enableUnknownComputerSupport = $dpProperties.EnableUnknownComputerSupport

    Write-Host "Distribution Point Name: $dpName"
    Write-Host "Enable PXE support for clients: $enablePxeSupport"
    Write-Host "Allow this distribution point to respond to incoming PXE requests:     
    $allowPxeRequests"
    Write-Host "Enable unknown computer support: $enableUnknownComputerSupport"
    Write-Host '---------------------------------------------'
}
else {
    Write-Host 'Distribution Point not found.' -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

It looks like `$dpproperties` doesn't contain the 3 values I'm looking for... I've tried:

```
Get-CMDistributionPointInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Is Pxe
```

but I don't find the 2 other values...
Can someone show me what i'm doing wrong ? Thx for your help

Comment: What happens if you do `Get-CMDistributionPoint -SiteSystemServerName $serverName |Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmbeddedProperties`? What property names are being listed then?

Comment: sorry @MathiasR.Jessen i'm newbie in stackoverflow, i can't add the total list of the properties : ADSiteName
AgreeDOINCLicense
AllowInternetClients
AvailableContentLibDrivesList
AvailablePkgShareDrivesList BindExcept
BindPolicy
BITS download
CertificateContextData
CertificateExpirationDate
CertificateFile
CertificatePFXData
CertificateType
Description
DiskSpaceDOINCDoincEnabled
DPDrive
DPMonEnabled
DPMonPriority
DPMonSchedule
DPShareDrive
DPUsageEnabled
EnableLEDBATFlags
IdentityGUID
InstallInternetServer
IPSubnets
IPv6Prefixes
IsActive
IsAnonymousEnabled

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen IsMulticast
IsPullDP
IsPXE
LocalDriveDOINC
MinFreeSpace
PreStagingAllowed
Priority
PXEPassword
RemoveWDS
ResponseDelay
RetainDOINCCache
Server Remote Name
SslStateSupportUnknownMachines
TokenAuthEnabled
TransferRate
UdaSetting
UpdateBranchCacheKey 
Version

Answer (score 0):

I think you got two things confused here:
**EnableUnknownComputerSupport** is the cmdlet parameter name you use in der [Add-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/add-cmdistributionpoint?view=sccm-ps) and [Set-CMDistributionPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/set-cmdistributionpoint?view=sccm-ps) Commands respectively (to toggle that setting to true).

If you query the EmbeddedProperties of Get-CMDistributionPoint however the Property is called **SupportUnknownMachines** (you can see some of the names of the those properties in the [SMS_DistributionPointInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/servers/configure/sms_distributionpointinfo-server-wmi-class) docu, unfortunately some seem be missing too). It is of the [SMS_EmbeddedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/servers/configure/sms_embeddedproperty-server-wmi-class) WMI type so you have to access it like this:

```
$enableUnknownComputerSupport = $dp.EmbeddedProperties.SupportUnknownMachines.Value
```

As SMS_EmbeddedProperty does not seem to support booleans, it is a integer, but I would assume it is just 1 for enabled and 0 for disabled (I cannot confirm this in our system as we do not have a DP with the setting enabled).

Comment: You are totally right thx ! but i don't find the values even though i modify the script as you said... what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I've tried again :  $enablePxeSupport = $DP.EmbeddedProperties.IsPxeEnabled.Value is empty
    $allowPxeRequests = $DP.EmbeddedProperties.RespondToPxeRequests.Value isempty
    $enableUnknownComputerSupport = $dp.EmbeddedProperties.SupportUnknownMachines.Value : Works ! i'm lost, how do i find the equivalence for IsPXEEnabled and RespondtopxeRequest ?

Comment: Ok the answer to that is tricky there is no really great way to find specific values. First step would be to check the wmi class where this comes from, (google sms_distributionpointinfo) in the docu you find IsPXE which says it reflects enabled. You also find isActive which is described as "true if this PXE is active." Others (https://github.com/paulwetter/DocumentConfigMgrCB/blob/master/DocumentCMCB.ps1) seem to check this for the "responding". I would try it and if possible change the value in the console and watch. If all fails do $dp | select * (will be huge) and compare after changing.

Comment: Thx a lot for the posh you've found you are excellent ! i'm gonna work on it and get back if i resolve my case .